# Ha Boel Aramis Kanoim Pogen Bo

Tags: sources-mekorot, slave-serve-eved-avadim

I saw somewhere (I *think* that it was in a Tosphos) that since an Eved Canaani and a Shifcha Canaanis have some Kedushas Yisroel (they are mechuyavim in the mitzvos of a woman), the principal of Ha Boel Aramis etc. and all of its ramifications would apply to them as well.
I would like to locate this source.

Comment: The Milchemes says it doesn't apply to a Jewish woman who is Boel Arami, by the way, as the offspring would be Jewish ... anyhow that's quite a statement! Could be, but ... it's news to me.

Comment: What is the principle of  Ha Boel Aramis?

Comment: @ClintEastwood see here - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.9.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi

Comment: @arnold - all the mefarshim on the mishnah (linked above) talk specifically about a woman who is ovdei avoda zara.

Comment: The actions of zealots don't follow regular halacha. If the zealot is so disgusted at the slaves action and says he was protecting hashem's honor, the zealot gets away with it.